# "Abuse one's power on someone", "abuse one's power against someone", or "abuse one's power toward someone"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me which preposition: *on*, *against* or *toward* I use with the expression *abuse one's power* meaning that the person has been affected by the abuse. For example:

> The policeman abused his power **on** a citizen and was fired.
>
> The policeman abused his power **against** a citizen and was fired.
>
> The policeman abused his power **toward** a citizen and was fired.

If any of the sentence sounds natural, could you tell me what would you say to get the message across?

Comment: I haven't come across an instance of following **abused his power** with a preposition in this context, referring to the victim. None of them sounds natural.

Comment: Could you pleas  tell me what would sound natural?

Comment: **His treatment of a citizen amounted to an abuse of power**.  **He abused his power when he mistreated a citizen**.